# Difference Between dot operator and brackets in jsp el

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have so class:

```
public class MyClass{
   String name;
   Map map;
   int [] arrInt;
//get  set
}
```

I  create Object:

```
MyClass  mc = new MyClass  ();
```

In jsp I can write so code:

```
${mc.name}
```

and it the same as

```
${mc["name"]}
```

There are  exist differencies between dot operator and bracket operator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have exactly the same meaning.  The dot style is often easier to read.  You need the bracket style if the index is going to be given by an expression (e.g. `mc[name]` instead of `mc["name"]`).

Comment: Not true,In case of group of objects.

Comment: Certain it's true. If the key is an expression you have to use the[] syntax. 'Groups' isn't a well-defined term in EL.

Answer (score 2):

`${person.age}` looks simpler than `${person["age"]}` but the **second statement** has some ***advantages***.

> When you use the **dot operator** ,the thing on the left can be only a Map
>   or a Bean ,and the thing on the right must **follow java coding**
>   **standards** (like for naming). But **with [ ]** ,the thing on the left can
>   also be a `List or an Array`. That means the `thing on the right` can be a
>   **number or an identifier that doesn't fit in the Java naming rules**.

**ex**:
**1.** You can use

`${ mapObject["com.electron.name"] }`

but **not**

```
${ mapObject.com.electron.name }
```

**2.** Also you can use **nested expression** by using `[ ]` ,like

`array[array2[array3[0]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your current scenarios is ok ,but but   `[  ]`  notation really helps,when you are dealing with groups.

[JSTL overview](http://strutscr.uw.hu/0066.html)

```
Accessing Objects
```

> The JSTL expression language provides a simple mechanism for accessing objects and their properties. The dot (.) operator is used to traverse object hierarchies and access properties. The following snippet illustrates a basic example of the dot operator's usage:

```
<c:out value="${customer.address.city}"/>
```

In this example, the dot operator is used to access the customer object's address property and then the address object's city property. Each instance of the dot operator in the expression evaluates to a getter method call for the property on the left of the operator. Thus, the first dot will call a getAddress( ) method on the customer object. The second dot will then call a getCity( ) method on the object returned from the getAddress( ) call. In order for the dot operator to work, the object on the right of the operator must have a getter method for the property on the left of the operator. Otherwise, the operator will fail.
As you can see, this method of traversing object hierarchies is quick and simple. Without JSTL, you'd have to use a JSP expression similar to the following to access properties down a hierarchy:

```
<%= customer.getAddress().getCity() %>
```

The dot operator is great for accessing simple properties; however, it doesn't allow you to access elements of arrays or collections. **For that, JSTL has the brackets ([ ]) operator.** The brackets operator allows you to specify the index of an element you want to access, as shown next:

```
<c:set var="highBid" value="${bids[0]}"/>
```

This approach works for arrays and list-based collections. For map-based collections, you specify the key for the element you want to access, as shown next:

```
<c:set var="color" value="${param['color']}"/>
```